# Audio App (client/server design), do I need onLoadChildren() method?

Tags: android

I made my first audio app (music player) using client/server architecture: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowserservice.html

It works ok. I tested only with one song - I set a source (Uri) for `MediaPlayer` instance in my `MediaService` class using hardcoded way just for a test.

It plays this song normally, displays information about it in notification and lockscreen, play/pause button also works ok.

But now I need to make a playlist.
What is the best practice to do it?
Is it ok just to make an instance `List` of some `MyAudio` class, set fields like title, artist, source (and so on) of all `MyAudio` instances (when user picked some folder from his device storage) and then just use them in `onSkipToNext`, `onSkipToPrevious` of `MediaSessionCallback`, `onCompletion` of 'MediaPlayer'.

There is a line `List<MediaItem> mediaItems = new ArrayList<>();` in `onLoadChildren()` method from that client/server architecture example.

But do I need this? Or these methods (with `getRoot()`) just needed to give other apps an opportunity to use my MediaService to get list of music/playlist.
If I don't this that I can don't care about these methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of using `MediaItem`s is that it gives you a pre-built mechanism for passing a list of objects available to play between your `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` and your UI as explained in [this MediaBrowserService blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/mediabrowserservicecompat-and-the-modern-media-playback-app-7959a5196d90#ce63) - if you build your own `MyAudio` class, it is much more difficult to pass that between the two in any clean way.

Of course, if you only have a fixed playlist of what is currently being played (and not a list of items to select from), you're probably better suited to use the queue APIs in `MediaSession`. Namely, [setQueue()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html#setQueue(java.util.List%3Candroid.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.QueueItem%3E)) and [getQueue()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaControllerCompat.html#getQueue()).

Comment: Yeah, I guess I can use `onLoadChildren` to update UI when getting list of `MediaItem`, but first I have to add somewhere my music (e.g. if I have list of strings with songs' sources).`MediaBrowser` must have some library which can I use to add music to it from UI, and set this music to list of `MediaItem` in `onLoadChildren` to update UI again (if user closed the app)

Comment: Generally media apps don't require the user to manually select the sources of their music (a streaming service will already know its content, local playback usually involves reading directly from [MediaStore.Audio](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.html), etc.). You can, of course, send any custom command (like 'add this source') via the [sendCommand method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaControllerCompat.html#sendCommand(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.ResultReceiver))

Comment: there seems to be methods to browser music with MediaStore of a specific folder, ok, I'll try somehow to use only service, mediastore in it and build UI with onLoadChildren